# Angular1 : How to pass multiple object as request body?

Tags: java, angularjs

I am using angular1 with java, spring-mvc framework. And from frontend service/controller , I need to pass 2 different types of object to the java-backend-controller. For example, say my 2 objects are:

```
self.basicBean = {id: null, name: self.fileInfo.fileLocation};
self.delimiterToChk = {name:'', value:self.delimiter}
```

My current javascript controller which is **seeing error** at this point is :

```
return $http.post( 'submenu/layout/guess/' + clientId + '/' + maxColumns  + "/" + origin ,
            delimiterObj,
            folderPathBean)
            .then(
                function( response )
                {
                    return response.data;
                },
                function( errResponse )
                {
                    console.error( 'Error while guessFieldLayout' );
                    return $q.reject( errResponse );
                }
            );
```

My backend java-controller looks like :

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/layout/guess/{clientId}/{maxColumns}/{origin}", method = RequestMethod.POST )
public ResponseEntity<?> guessFieldLayout( @PathVariable( "clientId" ) long clientId,
        @PathVariable( "maxColumns" ) int maxColumns,
        @RequestBody Delimiter delimiterObj,
        @PathVariable( "origin" ) String origin,
        @RequestBody BasicBean basicBeanFolderPath )
{
    try{}
```

}

I am seeing 400 error and guessing it is because I am not suppose to send the objects as 2 Request body. However, how to put it in one request body and how to map that at java controller end? Any example available?

Comment: Just send one object with two fields.

Comment: And then how to extract at the other end?

Comment: By mapping the JSON to a Java class with two fields, too.

Comment: So, if I now send as a self.objectTosend = {
                        filaInfo:self.basicBean,
                        delimiter:self.layout.delimiter
                    }   , can I just map it as @RequestBody List<JsonObject> myObj instead of creating a class?

Comment: No, you can't. A List in Java maps to an array in JSON. Not to an object with two fields. Just create a class with a field named fileInfo of type BasicBean and a field  delimiter of type DelimiterObj. I.e. a class matching the structure of the JSON you're sending. It's 3 lines of code, and getters and setters generated by your IDE.

Comment: Note that you *can* just write an interface with `getFileInfo()` and `getDelimiter()` methods and use that as your `@RequestBody`; you don't have to actually implement the class.